# Print Bingo cards

Tags: matrix, algorithm

As you know, the Bingo cards are structured as follows:

- a table with three rows and nine columns;
- in each row there are exactly five numbers;
- in each column can be from zero to three numbers in ascending order from top to bottom;
- in the first column can be the numbers from one to nine;
- in the second column may be the numbers from ten to nineteen (similar rule to eighth column);
- in the ninth column can be the numbers from eighty to ninety.

To print any table of that type, I wrote the following code:

```
matrixgen := Module[{A},
  A = ConstantArray[0, {3, 9}];
  A[[All, 1]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 3]];
  A[[All, 2]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, 3]];
  A[[All, 3]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, 3]];
  A[[All, 4]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39}, 3]];
  A[[All, 5]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49}, 3]];
  A[[All, 6]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59}, 3]];
  A[[All, 7]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69}, 3]];
  A[[All, 8]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79}, 3]];
  A[[All, 9]] = Sort[RandomChoice[{0, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90}, 3]];
  Return[A]]

checkrow[A_] := Module[{flag, i},
  flag = 0; i = 1;
  While[i <= 3 && flag == 0,
   If[Count[A[[i]], 0] != 4,
    flag = 1]; i++];
  Return[flag]]

checkcolumn[A_] := Module[{flag, j},
  flag = 0; j = 1;
  While[j <= 9 && flag == 0,
   If[(A[[1]][[j]] == A[[2]][[j]] && A[[1]][[j]] != 0) ||
     (A[[1]][[j]] == A[[3]][[j]] && A[[1]][[j]] != 0) ||
     (A[[2]][[j]] == A[[3]][[j]] && A[[2]][[j]] != 0),
    flag = 1]; j++];
  Return[flag]]

cards[n_] := Module[{A, k},
  k = 1;
  While[k <= n,
   A = matrixgen;
   If[checkrow[A] == 0 && checkcolumn[A] == 0,
    Print[A]; k++]
   ]]
```

where zero pointed to the empty cells, but also writing trivially:

```
cards[1]
```

even after several million cycles do not get any print.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generating cards with random arrangements, then selecting only those that fit your constraints is likely to be *extremely inefficient*. It may very well be that your code is working just fine (although I haven't checked all details) but it's simply *so unlikely* to come up with a proper card by rejection sampling that it simply never does in the time you have had the patience to run it.

I suggest instead that you directly generate correct cards. First, generate a card completely filled with numbers from the necessary ranges. Then, replace four randomly selected positions in each row with "holes". This process is guaranteed to produce a correct card every time you run it.

In addition to that, I translated the card generation, range selection etc into somewhat more idiomatic *Mathematica*, i.e. by avoiding loops and trying "vectorize" the code, i.e. by operating on complete lists at once, rather than on their single elements.

Here are the result. `filledcard` is a helper function generating a $3\times 9$ card completely filled with numbers; `holes` generates a random list of positions at which blanks should be found; `generatecards[n]` generates $n$ random cards by calling those two functions and combining their results.

```
Clear[filledcard, holes, generatecards]

ranges = {Range[9]}~Join~Table[10 i + j, {i, 1, 7}, {j, 0, 9}]~Join~{Range[80, 90]};

filledcard := Transpose@(Sort[RandomSample[#, 3]] & /@ ranges)
holes := Table[RandomSample[Range[9], 4], {3}]

generatecards[n_Integer] :=
 Table[
   MapThread[
     ReplacePart[#1, Thread[#2 -> ""]] &,
     {filledcard, holes}
   ],
   {n}
 ]
```

Here is sample output:

```
Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All] & /@ generatecards[12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Manu Glad you liked it! For your second request, you might have to go back to creating many cards at once, then rejecting those with an improper amount of overlap between rows. It does not sound very fair to the players tough :-)

Comment: @Manu This kind of "moving target" questions is rather frowned upon here, as it makes the existing answers typically obsolete and useless. You should probably restore the old version of the question, and move your current code and problem to a new one.