# Print Bingo cards with at most n elements in common by row

Tags: performance-tuning, programming

Starting from the [@MarcoB's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137552/print-bingo-cards), I wrote:

```
generatecard[] := Module[{filledcard, holes, ranges},
  ranges = {Range[9]}~Join~Table[10 i + j, {i, 1, 7}, {j, 0, 9}]~Join~{Range[80, 90]};
  filledcard = Transpose@(Sort[RandomSample[#, 3]] & /@ ranges);
  holes = Table[RandomSample[Range[9], 4], {3}];
  Return[MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, Thread[#2 -> ""]] &, {filledcard, holes}]]]

printcards[m_, n_] := Module[{card, flag, i, j, memo},
  card = generatecard[];
  Print[Grid[card, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All]];
  memo = ConstantArray[0, m]; memo[[1]] = card;
  flag = 0; i = 2;
  While[i <= m,
   card = generatecard[];
   j = 1; flag = 0;
   While[j < i && flag == 0,
    If[Length[Union[memo[[j, 1]], card[[1]]]] < 11 - n ||
      Length[Union[memo[[j, 2]], card[[2]]]] < 11 - n ||
      Length[Union[memo[[j, 3]], card[[3]]]] < 11 - n, flag = 1];
    j++];
   If[flag == 0,
    Print[Grid[card, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All]];
    memo[[i]] = card; 
    i++]]]
```

and writing, for example:

```
printcards[10, 2]
```

I get printing of 10 Bingo cards with a maximum of 2 elements in common to row. Unfortunately, like all my scripts, efficiency is very bad: I can not print even 10 cards with zero common elements to row. A few ideas to optimize it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better attempt at answering your actual question, i.e. of generating cards that have *at most* an indicated amount of overlaps between the numbers contained in each row. The function below allows you to indicate this overlap row by row as well, i.e. you can have different overlaps on each row.

The function is fed from a "card repository", i.e. a large collection of valid cards that was separately generated (code to generate at the bottom, see also [my answer to your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137565/27951) regarding that code). Alternatively, one could generate cards on the fly. I have not included that in this version, but I might at a later time.

The process is iterative, so it can be somewhat time-consuming, and it may also fail to generate as many cards as requested, depending on the strictness of the conditions, and on the random starting point. In case of failure, all the cards found when the card repository is exhausted are reported.

```
Clear[uniquecards]
uniquecards[n_Integer, singleoverlap_Integer?(# >= 0 &)] := uniquecards[n, {singleoverlap, singleoverlap, singleoverlap}]
uniquecards[n_Integer, {first_Integer?(# >= 0 &), second_Integer?(# >= 0 &), 
   third_Integer?(# >= 0 &)}] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {foundcounter, attemptcounter, working, found},

  foundcounter = 0;
  attemptcounter = 1;(*The first "attempt" is the first card considered*)
  working = RandomChoice[cardrepo];

  Print@Grid[{
     {"Found:", Dynamic[foundcounter]},
     {"Examined:", Dynamic[attemptcounter]}},
     Alignment -> Right
    ];

  found = Reap[
     Do[
      If[And @@ 
        Thread[
         Length /@ MapThread[Intersection[#1, #2] &, {working, DeleteCases[card, "", -1]}] <= {first, second, third}
        ],
       Sow[card];
       working = MapThread[Join, {working, card}];
       If[++foundcounter == n, Break[]]
      ];
      ++attemptcounter,
      {card, RandomSample[cardrepo]}
     ]
    ][[2, 1]];

  Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All] & /@ found
 ]
```

Just for fun, the function currently keeps track and displays the number of cards found that satisfy the conditions, and the number of cards tested. This was useful while building the function, but now it is just eye candy, of course, and could be removed (remove/comment out the `Print@....` code portion).

Two syntax forms are possible, either with a single number of acceptable overlaps which is the same for all rows, or a triplet of numbers, one for each row.

Here are usage examples:

```
uniquecards[3, {2, 3, 1}]
```

[image: different]

```
uniquecards[15, 2]
```

[image: same]

---

Code to generate the card repository `cardrepo`:

```
Clear[generatecard]
generatecard[] := Module[{filledcard, holes, ranges},
  ranges = {Range[9]}~Join~Table[10 i + j, {i, 1, 7}, {j, 0, 9}]~Join~{Range[80, 90]};
  filledcard = Transpose@(Sort[RandomSample[#, 3]] & /@ ranges);
  holes = Table[RandomSample[Range[9], 4], {3}];
  MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, Thread[#2 -> ""]] &, {filledcard, holes}]
 ]

cardrepo = Table[generatecard[], {1000000}];
```

Answer (score 2):

The following approach does not lead exactly to your desired result, but is a starting point.

We first generate a large (1,000,000) repository of random, valid cards:

```
cardrepo = Table[generatecard, {1000000}];
```

This is somewhat time consuming, but not overwhelmingly so: on my laptop, it takes 1.5 minutes.

We then "sieve" this repository, by

1. grouping cards that contain the same numbers in their first row, then:
2. taking one representative from each group, randomly (using `RandomChoice`);
3. repeating the process for rows 2 and 3, each time starting from the reduced stack of cards obtained at the end of the previous step.

Here it is in code, together with a helper function `sieve` that carries out an elementary step of the selection process:

```
Clear[sieve]
sieve[repository_, row_] := RandomChoice /@ GatherBy[repository, #[[row]] &]

selected = Fold[sieve[#1, #2] &, cardrepo, {1, 2, 3}];
```

The result is a reduced card stack, from which you can select however many unique cards you would like, e.g. randomly using `RandomSample`. Here are 15 such cards:

```
Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All] & /@ RandomSample[selected, 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Manu please take a look at the second answer I just posted; it should be better suited for your goals.